# Background of the app is showing white in lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am creating an app that supports from Api 15 to 23. It was working well on all phone including lollipop.But when I tested on another lollipop phone it is showing the background of one screen as white. I tried to reduce the resolution of the background image but of no use. If anyone knows the answer please do help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/homeplainbgone">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hometop" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:background="@drawable/homelogo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lL_home_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eT_home_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lL_home_search"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#eaeaea" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lL_home_firstlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_search"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_home_incio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:src="@drawable/sone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_home_ultimas"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:src="@drawable/stwo" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lL_home_secondlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lL_home_firstlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_home_radio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:src="@drawable/sthree"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_home_tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:src="@drawable/sfour" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lL_home_secondlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_home_descarga"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:src="@drawable/sfive" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_home_contactio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:src="@drawable/ssix" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz..post ur code...

Comment: are you using image in the background? Some screenshot or code will be helpful.

Comment: please..if u know the answer let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the class for resize your high resolution image aspect ratio and for memory management.

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;


/**
 * A simple subclass of {@link } that resizes images from resources given a target width
 * and height. Useful for when the input images might be too large to simply load directly into
 * memory.
 */
public class ImageResizer {

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filename,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight, boolean isLow) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        if (isLow) {
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        }
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }


    /**
     * Calculate an inSampleSize for use in a {@link BitmapFactory.Options} object when decoding
     * bitmaps using the decode* methods from {@link BitmapFactory}. This implementation calculates
     * the closest inSampleSize that is a power of 2 and will result in the final decoded bitmap
     * having a width and height equal to or larger than the requested width and height.
     *
     * @param options   An options object with out* params already populated (run through a decode*
     *                  method with inJustDecodeBounds==true
     * @param reqWidth  The requested width of the resulting bitmap
     * @param reqHeight The requested height of the resulting bitmap
     * @return The value to be used for inSampleSize
     */
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }

            // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
            // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
            // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
            // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
            // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

            long totalPixels = width * height / inSampleSize;

            // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
            final long totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

            while (totalPixels > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
                totalPixels /= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
        // END_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
    }
}
```

In your activity do the following..

```
 private Bitmap mBackground;
 private Drawable mBackgroundDrawable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.entrance);
    initComponents();
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void initComponents() {
  RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
    final Resources res = getResources();
    int[] dimensions = Util.getDisplayDimensions(this);
                mBackground = ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(res, R.drawable.homeplainbgone, dimensions[0], dimensions[1], false);
    mBackgroundDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, mBackground);
    layout.setBackground(mBackgroundDrawable);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   recycle();
   super.onDestroy();
}

private void recycle() {
            if (mBackground != null) {
                mBackground.recycle();
                mBackground = null;
                if (mBackgroundDrawable != null)
                    mBackgroundDrawable = null;
                 }
          }
```

Use the following method for get display dimensions..

```
public static int[] getDisplayDimensions(Activity activity) {
        int[] dimensions = new int[2];
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        dimensions[0] = metrics.widthPixels;
        dimensions[1] = metrics.heightPixels;
        return dimensions;
    }
```

Replace your xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hometop" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/homelogo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lL_home_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eT_home_search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lL_home_search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#eaeaea" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lL_home_firstlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_search"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iV_home_incio"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:src="@drawable/sone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iV_home_ultimas"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:src="@drawable/stwo" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lL_home_secondlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lL_home_firstlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iV_home_radio"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:src="@drawable/sthree"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iV_home_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:src="@drawable/sfour" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lL_home_secondlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iV_home_descarga"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:src="@drawable/sfive" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iV_home_contactio"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:src="@drawable/ssix" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this code is showing out of memory exception.I dont know why

Comment: It seems ur using too much images.it's oki if those not too much large..now try do not put `android:background="@drawable/homeplainbgone"` in xml as we are doing it programmatically..